# Split/Reformat String

Tags: string, split, reformat

I want to split a string and replace some values. The string is a date that looks like this '08/26/2009' I want to reformat it so that it replaces the / with a - so that it looks like this '08-26-2009'

The string is passed into a variable y, so my line looks like this

```
test = y.split("/")
print y
```

return this ['8', '26', '2009']

I just can't figure out how to reformat it to place the dash between the day month and year.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: You might want to tell us what language you're using...

Split functions usually return an array so you'd manipulate it the same as you do other arrays in that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use replace instead of split.

```
test = y.replace('/', '-');
```

(assuming this is Java)

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Python, but that worked perfectly. Thank you for your response!

Comment: Sure thing! Just a little friendly advice: try your best to accept answers to your questions when someone does help you out. It helps other people down the line to figure out the answer to a question quickly without having to read all the answers, and also marks the question as answered. And of course people don't mind the extra reputation ;-)